# Controlling content of HTML/CSS columns

Tags: html, css, jekyll

Is it possible, using HTML/CSS to create several columns and control what the content of each column is?

I want to have a page footer with one division that contains three columns and I want to control what goes into each column. Following this, I want a division below the columns that fills the width of the display.

The solution does not need to use CSS columns but should conform to the visual effect that I want. I am using Jekyll if this makes a difference.

Here is a screenshot of my attempt at getting this to work. It is based on the Jekyll theme Minima and modified myself. I am running in Google Chrome v 76 using Jekyll 4.0.0 as a web site generator on Ubuntu 18.04.3 desktop. The problem also occurs when using Firefox v 69.

Here is a screenshot of the failing code:
[image: Three columns not working].

If you look near the bottom of the page, there are supposed to be three columns, each with their unique content. Two columns are handled correctly, but the text that should display in the third column on the right of the screen displays on a line by itself below the columns. The original HTML and CSS did support 3 columns successfully and all I did was to change the relative sizes of the columns. The HTML for the footer and the relevant CSS is shown below.

HTML for footer:

```
<footer class="site-footer h-card">
    <data class="u-url" href="{{ "/" | relative_url }}"></data>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="footer-col-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-col one-half">
        <h2 class="footer-heading">{{ site.stitle | escape }}</h2>
          <ul class="contact-list">
            <li class="p-name">
              {%- if site.author -%}
                {{ site.author | escape }}
              {%- endif -%}
              </li>
              {%- if site.email -%}
              <li><a class="u-email" href="mailto:{{ site.email }}">{{ site.email }}</a></li>
              {%- endif -%}
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-col one-half">
          <p>{{- site.description | escape -}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="social-links">
          {%- include social.html -%}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <p>
      </br>
      <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">
        <img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by/4.0/88x31.png" /></a><br />This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License</a>.
      </p>   
    </div>

  </footer>
```

The relevant base CSS from the Minima theme is displayed below:

```
.footer-col-wrapper {
  @include relative-font-size(0.9375);
  color: $grey-color;
  margin-left: -$spacing-unit / 2;
  @extend %clearfix;
}

.footer-col {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: $spacing-unit / 2;
  padding-left: $spacing-unit / 2;
}

.footer-col-1 {
  width: -webkit-calc(35% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
  width:         calc(35% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

.footer-col-2 {
  width: -webkit-calc(20% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
  width:         calc(20% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

.footer-col-3 {
  width: -webkit-calc(45% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
  width:         calc(45% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

@include media-query($on-laptop) {
  .footer-col-1,
  .footer-col-2 {
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
    width:         calc(50% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
  }

  .footer-col-3 {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
    width:         calc(100% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
  }
}
```

My modifications to the CSS are shown below:

```
---
---

@import "minima";

$background-color:#fefff6 !default;

.footer-col-1 {
  width: -webkit-calc(35% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
  width:         calc(35% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

.footer-col-2 {
  width: -webkit-calc(25% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
  width:         calc(25% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

.footer-col-3 {
  width: -webkit-calc(40% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
  width:         calc(40% - (#{$spacing-unit} / 2));
}

.footer-copyright {
    background-color: eaff08;
    display: inline;
}
```

Here is the rendered HTML for the footer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Begin Jekyll SEO tag v2.6.1 -->
<title>Blog posts relating to maintaining a software development site | I use blog posts to help me think about what I want to do and this site is where the posts live.</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.0.0" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Blog posts relating to maintaining a software development site" />
<meta name="author" content="Jonathan Gossage" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta name="description" content="I use blog posts to help me think about what I want to do and this site is where the posts live." />
<meta property="og:description" content="I use blog posts to help me think about what I want to do and this site is where the posts live." />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:4000/" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:4000/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Blog posts relating to maintaining a software development site" />
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@type":"WebSite","headline":"Blog posts relating to maintaining a software development site","url":"http://localhost:4000/","name":"Blog posts relating to maintaining a software development site","author":{"@type":"Person","name":"Jonathan Gossage"},"description":"I use blog posts to help me think about what I want to do and this site is where the posts live.","@context":"https://schema.org"}</script>
<!-- End Jekyll SEO tag -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/main.css"><link type="application/atom+xml" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:4000/feed.xml" title="Blog posts relating to maintaining a software development site" /></head>
<body><header class="site-header" role="banner">

  <div class="wrapper"><a class="site-title" rel="author" href="/">Blog posts relating to maintaining a software development site</a><nav class="site-nav">
        <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
        <label for="nav-trigger">
          <span class="menu-icon">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 18 15" width="18px" height="15px">
              <path d="M18,1.484c0,0.82-0.665,1.484-1.484,1.484H1.484C0.665,2.969,0,2.304,0,1.484l0,0C0,0.665,0.665,0,1.484,0 h15.032C17.335,0,18,0.665,18,1.484L18,1.484z M18,7.516C18,8.335,17.335,9,16.516,9H1.484C0.665,9,0,8.335,0,7.516l0,0 c0-0.82,0.665-1.484,1.484-1.484h15.032C17.335,6.031,18,6.696,18,7.516L18,7.516z M18,13.516C18,14.335,17.335,15,16.516,15H1.484 C0.665,15,0,14.335,0,13.516l0,0c0-0.82,0.665-1.483,1.484-1.483h15.032C17.335,12.031,18,12.695,18,13.516L18,13.516z"/>
            </svg>
          </span>
        </label>

        <div class="trigger"><a class="page-link" href="/2019-09-03-welcome-to-jekyll">Welcome to Jekyll!</a><a class="page-link" href="/about/">About</a></div>
      </nav></div>
</header>
<main class="page-content" aria-label="Content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="home">
<h2 class="post-list-heading">Posts</h2>
    <ul class="post-list"><li><span class="post-meta">Sep 4, 2019</span>
        <h3>
          <a class="post-link" href="/requirements:/2019/09/04/Customize-Development-System-Iso">
            Customize Development System Iso
          </a>
        </h3></li></ul>

    <p class="rss-subscribe">subscribe <a href="/feed.xml">via RSS</a></p></div>

      </div>
    </main><footer class="site-footer h-card">
    <data class="u-url" href="/"></data>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="footer-col-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-col one-half">
        <h2 class="footer-heading">Wise Old Bird</h2>
          <ul class="contact-list">
            <li class="p-name">Jonathan Gossage</li><li><a class="u-email" href="mailto:jgossage@gmail.com">jgossage@gmail.com</a></li></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-col one-half">
          <p>I use blog posts to help me think about what I want to do and this site is where the posts live.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="social-links"><ul class="social-media-list"><li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jonathan.gossage.3"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#facebook"></use></svg> <span class="username">jonathan.gossage.3</span></a></li><li><a href="https://github.com/jfgossage"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#github"></use></svg> <span class="username">jfgossage</span></a></li><li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/JonathanGossage"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#twitter"></use></svg> <span class="username">JonathanGossage</span></a></li></ul>
</div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <p>
      </br>
      <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">
        <img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by/4.0/88x31.png" /></a><br />This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License</a>.
      </p>   
    </div>

  </footer>

<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by/4.0/88x31.png" /></a><br />This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License</a>.</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What does "control ... the content" mean? As the web developer you control _everything_.

Comment: @isherwood Place specific content in a column.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jekyll, but you might want to provide example markup and content.

Comment: @isherwood I am trying to determine what might work, as a result, I have little that works. I only have a non-working example.

Comment: That's a start. It might shed light on what you're trying to accomplish. Don't be shy.

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML from the site. It's hard to debug code when we have to figure out what the variables are outputting.

Comment: @disinfor I am new to Jekyll which generated the HTML code and the CSS.  I have no idea where the code is stored.

Comment: @Jonathan I just meant, paste what's in the source code from your browser. Because your browser contains the rendered HTML.

Comment: @disinfor This will give you the HTML but not the CSS which I suspect is a large part of the problem.

Comment: I know. But, you gave a screenshot with content. Then gave HTML with placeholder/variables leaving us guessing what column with what content is in the "wrong" place.

Comment: @disinfor I tried this, but I am not familiar with this aspect of the browser and I was unable to find what you want.

Comment: Right click on the browser and choose "view source", find the markup that you pasted above (only it will have your content) and put that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the quick glance, you have 3 columns by the following divs shown below inside the `footer-col-wrapper`

```
<div class="footer-col one-half">
  <h2 class="footer-heading">{{ site.stitle | escape }}</h2>
  ...
</div>

<div class="footer-col one-half">
  <p>{{- site.description | escape -}}</p>
</div>

<div class="social-links">
  {%- include social.html -%}
</div>
```

Two of them are calling the footer-col class which simply assigns `float:left` and margin properties. I don't see class for `one-half` in your css shared. I see you have `float-left-1/2/3` where you are trying to assign relative width, but they are never being called inside the divs. So a quick test is assigning those classes to the 3 divs interested. Unless `one-half` class has conflicting properties, but if your "I use blog post to help..." is your `site.description` I don't see it occupying only 50% of width.

Sometimes to understand how things work, it might be worth removing classes from all your div components and play around with inline `style` properties to see how they behave.

Comment: Or just using the dev inspector tools to see what classes are assigning what properties. Good catch on the `one-half` class.

Comment: Most of this code is from a working Jekyll theme - Minima- the Jekyll default theme. Everything that you talk about is part of the base theme which was working before I added my modifications.

Comment: The problem appears to be with Jekyll when it generates the source code. My CSS modifications are not being picked up. It is being investigated in the Jekyll environment.